# Color codes not aligned in the same line

Tags: css, angularjs

I am implementing color code picker in angular js. Tried to display the color picker in same line but it is not displaying in same line instead of that it is displaying in next lines.

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zRoXByx7zEscufzJG9aC?p=preview)

Can anyone help me to show the color code in same line? (don't want to use [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) tag).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myctrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

<div class="tdata" ng-repeat="color in colors"
ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}"
ng-click="setClickedRow($index)"
style="background-color:{{color}};">
  </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your  `div` to look like this:

```
<div style="display:table">
<div class="tdata" ng-repeat="color in colors"
ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}"
ng-click="setClickedRow($index)"
style="background-color:{{color}}; display:table-cell">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats worked. Thanks venkat. i also want some space between the color codes.

Comment: Add padding to the styling of the inner div

Answer (score 1):

Try this css for color aligned in same line:

```
.tdata.ng-scope {
  float: left;
}
```